# How to access JIRA from server

Tags: rest, curl, jira

I want to access JIRA from our server. I am on a intranet network and am logged in to one of our servers. I want to get list of all issues from the url: `https://ficcjira.xyz.com/browse/ABC` using a REST API call.

I don't know much curl but I'm doing something like this:

```
curl -D- -u username:password -x GET -H "Content-Type: application/json"  http://ficcjira.xyz.com/browse/ABC
```

But no good.

How exactly to do it?

Result response for the above curl:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://ficcjira.xyz.com/browse/abc
Server: BigIP
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control: proxy-revalidate
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Connection: Keep-Alive
Date: Fri, 10 Jun 2016 21:00:39 GMT
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with Java but the response is a simple redirect - you need to now do the same call but with the "Location" given.  At a guess you're just getting started but you'll likely want a library to handle things like redirects.  Jira [has one](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.jira.jira-rest-java-client/server/overview) though I can't vouch for how well it works.

Comment: I think you add the `-L` switch to follow redirects

Comment: @peeskillet Could you tell me the curl command to do it? I'm getting confused here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you posted, I see some errors:

1. You are not using the rest api URL, that should be something which has "rest/api/2" in the URL
2. You are not calling the api correctly - you should be sending a JQL search query, not just a browse. So your URL should probably end with "/search?jql=..."
3. You are not enclosing your URL in double quotes, so your curl command is being turned into 2 unix commands.

I suggest you first try this URL in your browser, and see if you get any results:

```
http://ficcjira.xyz.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=ABC
```

If you do, you can then try this curl call:

```
curl --globoff --insecure --silent -u username:password -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/json' "http://ficcjira.xyz.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=ABC"
```

You might get some more insight from my blog here: http://javamemento.blogspot.no/2016/05/jira-confluence-3.html

Why have you tagged this with java if you are using curl?

If you are indeed calling this REST API with a GET call from Java, you should be using jersey or Spring's RestTemplate to make the call.

On my blog here, you can get a sample of how to do this with RestTemplate

http://javamemento.blogspot.no/2016/06/rest-api-calls-with-resttemplate.html

Edit :

If you can access via browser but not curl, maybe you have a proxy set up. Try using the proxy option for the curl call

--proxy <[protocol://][user:password@]proxyhost[:port]>

Of course I hope you are already using the -L option as others already suggested?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I do get the result when I use the URL in my browser, but I get the same response when I use the curl you've mentioned. Just to re-iterate, I'm on a corporate network, logged on to one of our servers and there I'm using the curl command.

Comment: Smells like a proxy. Edited my answer.

Comment: I'm using this now: curl --proxy username:password@proxyhost:port --globoff -insecure --silent -u username:pass -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/json' "http://ficcjira.xyzt.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=ABC"
but getting the same response only. :|

Comment: Did you get the proxy info from the browser?

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with jira server. Seems to be more network related. Try pinging the jira server or telneting to it.

Comment: Did you try using the -L option with curl?

Comment: No, I haven't tried the -L option. How do I use it?

Comment: Is it possible for me to get a list of only certain fields of jira issues? Like search?jql=project=ABC gives me everything, but I only want 1 field of all the issues, i.e., "timetracking". How do I get that?

Comment: That's unrelated to this question. If my answer solved yoir problem, accept it. As for your comment, post a new question.

Comment: Cool! Glad I could help.